# For $u \in C^\infty(\Omega \backslash \{0\})$ harmonic with $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{u(x)}{|x|^{2-N}} = 0$, there is $v\in C^2(\Omega)$ with $u=v$ a.e.

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-functions

This was an exercice in my functional analysis course: Let $\Omega = B(0,1) \subset \mathbb R^N$, $N \ge 3$, and let $u \in C^\infty(\Omega \backslash \{0\})$ be a harmonic function such that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{u(x)}{|x|^{2 - N}} = 0.$$
Under these hypothesis, I must prove that there exists a harmonic function $v \in C^\infty(\Omega)$ such that $v = u$ on $\Omega\backslash \{0\}$, but I really do not see how I should do that. At some point I thought that I could try with *Weyl Lemma* that states the following:

> Let $u \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb R^n)$ with $\Delta u = 0$ in the sens of distributions. Then there exists $v \in C^2(\mathbb R^n)$ with $u = v$ a.e. and $\Delta v = 0$.

But as nothing ensure me that $u \in L^1_{loc}$ so... Moreover I do not use the fact that $u(x)/|x|^{2 - N}$ goes to zero.
Maybe do I have to construct explicitly the function $v$ ? I am really struggling with that, any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v$ solve the Dirichlet problem in $\Omega$ with $v=u$ on its boundary.
Let $g(x)=\lvert x \rvert^{2-N}$.
Then $g$ is positive and harmonic on $\Omega\setminus\{0\}$.
If $w=\left(u-v\right)/g$ we have
$w=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ and $\lim_{x \to 0}w(x)=0$. Also
$ 0=\Delta\!\left(u-v\right)/g=\Delta w+\left(2/g\right)\sum_{i}g_{x_{i}}w_{x{i}}$
so the maximum principle applies to $w$.

For any $y\in\Omega\setminus\{0\}$ and $\epsilon >0$ there exists $r\le \lvert y\rvert$
such that $\lvert w\rvert \le \epsilon$ on $\partial B(0,r)$ and therefore by
the maximum principle applied to $\Omega\setminus B(0,r)$ we have $\lvert w(y)\rvert \le \epsilon$.
Therefore $w=0$ throughout its domain.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just how do you deduce that $\Delta [(u - v)/g] = 0$ ?

Comment: I think my claim was rather that $\left(\Delta(u-v)\right)/g=0$. Because $u$ and $v$ are both harmonic.

Comment: And the following equality is a consequence of $\Delta (gw)=g\Delta w + 2\sum_{i}g_{x_{i}}w_{x_{i}}+w\Delta g$.